# Json parsing into swift 3 currency exchange values from bank accounts

Tags: swift, xcode8

Is it possible to fetch currency exchange rates from some banks           websites in my country, and is it legal ?

making an app specified to my country and have been trying for a week now but couldn't find an answer this is the code could you tell a solution?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {

     @IBOutlet weak var lblDisplay: UILabel!
     @IBOutlet weak var txtField: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var pkrView: UIPickerView!

     var myCurrency:[String] = []
     var myValue:[Double] = []
     var activeCurrency:Double = 0

      override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

     let url = URL(string: "http://ca-egypt.com")
     let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error)in

     if error != nil{
       print("error is here!")            
        }else{
            if let content = data{     
            do{         
          let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
           if let rates = myJson["rates"] as? NSDictionary{

            var firstOne = true

            for (key,value)in rates{
            self.myCurrency.append((key as? String)!)
            self.myValue.append((value as? Double)!)
                    }
                 }                       
                }catch{

              }

          }
       }
            self.pkrView.reloadAllComponents()
    }
        task.resume()


    }

    @IBAction func btnCalculateAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        lblDisplay.text = String(Double(txtField.text!)! * activeCurrency)

      }


     func numberOfComponents(in pickerView:  UIPickerView,umberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return myCurrency.count
    }
     func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return myCurrency.count
    }
     func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return myCurrency[row]
    }
     func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        activeCurrency = myValue[row]
    }

}
```

Image of the Error:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: please add the error message as plain text. so it can be indexed and is searchable

Comment: from witch line it starts?

Comment: scraping is normaly not legal

Comment: the link you provided dont give any JSON back

Comment: if the bank have a public API then it maybe legal to use it

Comment: use the debugger and lock where you an error

Comment: check all values before at last working line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello @Ali instead of fetching currency exchange rates from some banks websites, you can make use of some API, which are freely available or you can make use of paid API's. And off-course fetching currency exchange rates is illegal. They won't allow some-one to get values.

To get various countries currency-exchange rates use **[Fixer.io](http://fixer.io/)** , which are updating on daily basis, and yes it is freely available.

**[Fixer.io](http://fixer.io/)** is a free **JSON API** for current and historical foreign exchange rates, published by the European Central Bank. The rates are updated daily around 4PM CET.

**Example :**

**API Link :** http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD

```
 Alamofire.request("http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD") .responseJSON { response in

                if let arr = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject]
                {
                    let usd_val = (arr["rates"]?["INR"] as? NSNumber)!
                    print(usd_val)
                }

            }
```

By this way you can parse JSON API and use this currency exchange values, and if you want to get your country currency exchange value, then pass value.

**example :** To get current currency exchange value of Japan, then pass value of it. Like this. http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=JPY

Hope it helps you.